# How to verify a Kafka topic is indeed purged after setting retention time to 1 second

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to purge a topic in Kafka. So I set the retention time to 1 seconds using

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zk.com --entity-type topics --entity-name my_topic --alter --add-config retention.ms=1000
```

`log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000` i.e 5 mins so I wait 7 minutes and then reset the above retention value

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zk.com --entity-type topics --entity-name my_topic --alter --delete-config retention.ms
```

**How can I know for certain the the topic is indeed purged?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one of the ways to surely know that the topic is indeed purged is to read it using the option `--from-beginning`. For e.g

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server broker.com:9093 --topic my_topic --from-beginning
```

If it doesn't return any output, then we can be sure it's purged.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the `GetOffsetShell` tool. To get the start offset of each partition in the topic run

`bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell -broker-list localhost:9092 --topic <topic> --time -2`

and to get the end offsets run

`bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell -broker-list localhost:9092 --topic <topic> --time -1`

If reported offsets are equal, the topic is purged.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Unix script which i use in local, where you actually check the size of topic in disk:

```
# Kafka broker details
kafka_dir="/path/to/kafka"  
kafka_bin="${kafka_dir}/bin"
bootstrap_servers="kafka-broker1:9092,kafka-broker2:9092,kafka-broker3:9092"  


# Function to set retention to 0 for a topic
set_retention_to_zero() {
    topic="$1"
    ${kafka_bin}/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name "$topic" --add-config retention.ms=0
}

# Function to revert retention to previous value for a topic
revert_retention() {
    topic="$1"
    ${kafka_bin}/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name "$topic" --delete-config retention.ms
}

# Function to get data size of a topic
get_data_size() {
    topic="$1"
    data_size=$(${kafka_bin}/kafka-log-dirs.sh --describe --bootstrap-server "$bootstrap_servers" --topic-list "$topic" | grep "LogDir: " | awk '{print $5}')
    echo "$data_size"
}


# Main loop
while true; do
    # Set retention to 0 for each topic
    while IFS= read -r topic; do
        set_retention_to_zero "$topic"
    done < topics.txt

    # Check data size for each topic and send email alert
    while IFS= read -r topic; do
        data_size=$(get_data_size "$topic")
    done < topics.txt

    # Wait for some time before checking again (e.g., every 30 seconds)
    sleep 5

    # Revert retention to previous value for each topic
    while IFS= read -r topic; do
        revert_retention "$topic"
    done < topics.txt
done
```